# Angular ng-repeat appends rather than replaces DOM elements on successive $http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm trying to create a simple form with Angular, and need to render server-side validation errors.  Our REST API handles validation errors with a 422 status code and a JSON array of errors in the response body.

My Controller:

```
.controller('MyController, function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.save = function() {
    var promise = $http.post('http://myapi.net/resources', $scope.data)
      .success(function(data) {
        // Success
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.errors = data.errors;
      });
    $scope.errors = [];
    return promise;
  };
});
```

My Template:

```
<span ng-repeat="e in errors" class="error">
    {{e.field}} - {{e.message}}
</span>
```

The errors render correctly after the first POST, but if a second POST fails, the errors sent by the server are appended in the DOM.  The previous batch of errors remains, making it appear that no improvements to the data have been made.  Stepping through the code, the $scope variable has the correct data, but the DOM does not.  Is there a way to force ng-repeat to destroy all its previous DOM and build new ones?  Or is there a better way to debug this so I can see what is going on?

Comment: It should be destroying and re-building each time the `$scope` variable in the repeater is updated. Can you repro this in a fiddle?

Comment: @tymeJV I would be overjoyed to discover that it is.  Alas, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know what's going on with ng-repeat, but after 2 days I've discovered a workaround.  Using a second scope variable and a watch seems to restore the correct behavior:

```
.controller('MyController, function($scope, $http) {
  $scope._errors = [];
  $scope.$watch('_errors', function(val) {
    $scope.errors = val;
  });

  $scope.save = function() {
    var promise = $http.post('http://myapi.net/resources', $scope.data)
      .success(function(data) {
        // Success
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        $scope._errors = data.errors;
      });
    $scope.errors = [];
    return promise;
  };
});
```

Why this isn't necessary in the success callback is beyond me, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

As @tymeJV said it should just work. How about resetting the errors array using an empty array:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.save = function() {

    // always a good idea
    $scope.errors = [];
    // ...
});
```

[**Here's also a plunk, maybe you can recreate it there.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PatpirSrp0g9m0mPbor7?p=preview)

Comment: I played around with that plunker for a few minutes, and confirmed that it worked as written.  But it's testing the success handler, not the failure one.  Not being too familiar with Plunker's api mocking; not sure how to reproduce that there.

Comment: Yea unfortunately you can't throw any error responses that's why i put it in the success response. But have you tried resetting the error array in the save method? `$scope.save = function(){ $scope.errors = [] /* ... */ }`

Comment: Yes I have.  I can add that to the code if it would help.

Comment: You misunderstood me :) Try putting it right before your `var promise`.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  It will still get called before the promise is resolved.